# Getting extra information on Kendo UI Treeview node select event

Tags: php, kendo-treeview, kendo-template

**What I want**

To populate a div based on the Kendo Treeview node click, based on some extra information which is based from the server-side.

**What I am doing**

Using PHP to send arrays as data to kendo treeview control, here is the code:

```
 <?php
        require_once 'telerik/wrappers/php/lib/Kendo/Autoload.php';

        $treeview = new \Kendo\UI\TreeView('treeview');

        $dataSource = new \Kendo\Data\DataSource();
        $dataSource->data($data);

        // The 'treeview_collapse' JavaScript function will handle the  'treeview_collapse' event of the treeview
        $treeview->collapse('treeview_collapse');

        //Configuring treeview's dataTextField and set its dataSource.
        $treeview
                ->dataTextField('value')
                ->dataSource($dataSource)
                ->collapse("onCollapse")
                ->expand("onExpand")
                ->select("onSelect")
                ->navigate("onNavigate");

        //Output the TreeView by echoing the result of the render method.
        echo $treeview->render();
        ?>
```

$data variable has the following value:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => Please select from the following menu
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1. Manage Call Signature
            [type] => IMMEDIATE
            [closeSession] => false
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Please select your service
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 1. Manage MyStatus
                            [type] => IMMEDIATE
                            [closeSession] => true
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [value] => We are processing your MS request, you will be informed via SMS shortly
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 2. Manage IntroMe
                            [type] => IMMEDIAte
                            [closeSession] => true
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [value] => We are processing your IM request, you will be informed via SMS shortly
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 2. Subscribe
            [type] => FORWARD
            [closeSession] => false
            [forwardProtocol] => HTTPGET
        )

)
```

Through the above data [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ7Ln.png) treeview is rendered

So I want to retrieve [type], [closeSession] and [items] as well whenever a node is clicked.

**My Quetion**

1. How do I use template or any other technique to send extra info to the treeview
2. Retrieve that (non-displayed) info on "onSelect" js event